# RewriteCond and RewriteRule to do a permanent redirect to https://www. and keep the query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am using the mod_rewrite condition/rule as shown below to redirect a url to the www equivalent and ensure https.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

This, for example, converts `example.com/foo/bar` to `https://www.example.com/foo/bar` and works fine. However, if the link includes a query string (eg, `http://example.com/foo/bar?x=baz&y=qux`), the query string does not get appended. How can I modify my RewriteCond/RewriteRule above so that `http://example.com/foo/bar?x=baz&y=qux` is automatically converted to 
`https://www.example.com/foo/bar?x=baz&y=qux` with the query string appended? I have tried adding the QSA (Query String Append) flag in the rewrite rule and that doesn't help.

Comment: The rule as posted would already preserve the query string, so it's likely that _something else_ is removing it.

Answer (score 0):

You need the QSA flag (Query String Append)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC,QSA]
```

Second Option

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: I would post more of your htaccess as there may be things conflicting with it

Comment: Here's a little more:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]